# TransactionScope - commit on each iteration

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
    Imports System.Transactions
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Configuration

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private _ConString As String

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            Dim objDR As SqlDataReader
            _ConString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConnection").ConnectionString
            Dim objCon As New SqlConnection(_ConString)
            Dim objCommand As New SqlCommand
            objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Person"
            'Using scope As New TransactionScope()
            objCon.Open()
            Using scope As New TransactionScope()
                objCommand.Connection = objCon
                objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader
                Do While objDR.Read

                    Dim i As String = objDR("id2")
                    Dim objCommand2 As New SqlCommand
                    objCommand2.Connection = objCon
                    objCommand2.CommandText = "UPDATE Person SET URN=1 WHERE id2 = '" & i & "'"
                    objCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery() 'line 28
                    objCommand2.CommandText = "UPDATE Person SET URN=2 WHERE id2 = '" & i & "'"
                    objCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery() 'line 30
                    objCommand2.CommandText = "UPDATE Person SET URN=3 WHERE id2 = '" & i & "'"
                    objCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery() 'line 32
                Loop
                'scope.Complete() 'line 34
            End Using
            objDR.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The three update statements are executed even though scope.complete is commented out.  I believe this is because the connection is opened outside the TransactionScope.

If I wanted to loop through one million persons to issue these updates then there are two options:

1) Do all updates and commit the changes to the database at the end
2) Commit changes on each loop - then I would have to open a new connection for each loop.

Do developers always choose option 1? i.e. issue updates as a batch.

Comment: Probably a typo, but your update does not make much sense. URN is always 3 at the end

Comment: Steve, it was not a typo, but I can see why it has caused confusion (and hence there are no answers).  I stepped through the code in @Steve, Visual Studio and the three SQL statements were executed on lines: 28,30 and 32.  As this is a transaction I would not expect this to happen.  Can you confirm that the connection object must be opened inside the transactiom?

Comment: I never used `TransactionScope`, is it anything good? Why not use `Transaction` instead? I've gone through MSDN just now, and not getting why you are using the first one.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not commit all changes at once. With 1 million updates, the undo log will be huge, you may run into lock issues and the whole operation is likely to take unreasonable amount of time.
2. Issuing updates in batches is a good idea, just remember to set batch size to something reasonable. For example, 1000 records. You can have your updates run in parallel - it should be faster. If you can organize your updates into logical pieces, such as people by department - please do so, it would improve code maintainability in the long run.

Also, consider using parameters.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the docs it looks like the transaction scope needs to wrap the connection using block (which is missing).  So open scope, open connection, execute command, commit scope.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Connections, Commands, TransactionScope and Readers all implement IDisposable and require a using block (unless you decompile the code and verify that the activities in IDisposable are nonsense, like they are for DataSet, DataTable and that Bulk Insert thing)

And everything that Neolisk said. Batch updates unless you have a unique scenario where a partial update would be some sort of disaster. (more likely a massive transaction will be a worse disaster of another sort-- log files filling up or the db engine checking out for lunch for a crazy long time while it it digests a huge transaction)